# App giving bad performace when i try to repeat my action

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-bitmap

In my app, I have two intent. In first intent, i take image as input from gallery and camera. Then i send the uri to the next activity. Where i convert the uri into bitmap and apply some effect on bitmap. The activity contains two fragment. I do filtering inside a thread. App performs well for first time. But when i am back to my first activity and move to next, then it performs slowly.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageViewFragment.applyEffect(finalEffectNO);
                Message message = new Message();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(MESSAGE_KEY,"task is completed");
                message.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };

        thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fom the provided code example I can not tell what's wrong. Maybe the thread is started multiple times but does not finish. Make sure it is only started once (onResume might be called multiple times, for example).

There are many good libraries ([RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/How-To-Use-RxJava), [Koltin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines-basic-jvm.html), ...) which help with doing asynchonous work so no need to do the Threading manually.

Comment: Thread run for only one time. If i avoid thread, still i am getting same result.